# How does the IDE/Compiler know that a lambda expression is executed immediately and not saved for later use?

Tags: c#, lambda, compiler-warnings, code-analysis

The compiler (I'm using this word loosely here, somebody in my VS, Roslyn, R# toolchain) knows when I access a variable in a lambda expression, that if executed later might already be disposed. That's a great feature and a welcome warning. However, sometimes I know that a lambda expression will be executed *immediately* and not saved for later use, so this warning is wrong.

One might argue that the compiler cannot know whether the lambda expression is executed or kept for later use. Fun fact: it does. If I use this in a LinQ statement, I get the squiggly warning line, *except* for when I materialize the thing immediately with for example a call to `.ToList()`. Then the warning vanishes. So the compiler *knows* if a lambda is used once and discarded, or kept for later use.

Access to disposed closure with squiggly line:

[image]

How can I explain to my toolchain that my method (the `.ThrownFrom()` that takes a lambda) *is* in fact executing it immediately and keeps no reference to it?

Can I get the same effect that materializing LinQ has through attributes, patterns or other things I can set, or is that some hardcoded compiler magic specific to LinQ?

---

My Ignore class as an example:

```
public static class Ignore<TException> where TException : Exception
{
    public static void ThrownFrom([NotNull] Action action)
    {
        if (action is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }

        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (TException ex)
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just turn off R# then;)

Comment: You can disable this with a comment before the line saying `// ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure`. Feels a bit nasty though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One might argue that the compiler cannot know whether the lambda expression is executed or kept for later use.

Such an argument would be correct.  It assumed that any lambda could be invoked at any arbitrary point in the future of the application, and compiles the code accordingly.

> Fun fact: it does. If I use this in a LinQ statement, I get the squiggly warning line, except for when I materialize the thing immediately with for example a call to .ToList(). Then the warning vanishes. So the compiler knows if a lambda is used once and discarded, or kept for later use.

No, the compiler does no such thing.  Some code analysis tools attempt to determine if a given lambda could be invoked outside of a given scope, but they can't know. It's *impossible* to know in the general case, but you can sometimes know in certain specific cases.  They've simply harded-coded a bunch of specific case in which they do or don't know whether a lambda is invoked immediately or not (in this case, they've simply hard coded into the code analysis tool the fact that certain framework methods immediately invoke the provided delegate, and others hold onto it for later).  Given this, they will sometimes make mistakes, because there are lots of methods that they simply can't know if the delegate is held onto or not.

> How can I explain to my toolchain that my method (the .ThrownFrom() that takes a lambda) is in fact executing it immediately and keeps no reference to it?

You could look at the documentation for whatever code analysis tools your using.  They might provide a means of doing so, and they might not.

Comment: I agree with this:)

Comment: Holy Murphy... turns out that after three days of me trying to google this, if I just open the help page that is suggested by my code analysis tool for this warning, it's right on there. Facepalm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the answer from @Servy is absolutely correct (not surprising) and the solution to my problem is actually on my code analysis tool's help page for just that warning (surprising):

If you are using Resharper (that generates this warning) you can use the `[InstantHandle]` attribute to signal that this lambda expressions is in fact handled instantly.

So:

```
public static class Ignore<TException> where TException : Exception
{
    public static void ThrownFrom([InstantHandle][NotNull] Action action)
    {
        if (action is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
        }

        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (TException ex)
        {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```